# How to remove extra comma after the last number in loop

Tags: java, string, loops

Hi I'm just new at programming java. So I was just stuck in this example code:

```
for(int i=0; i < something.length; i++){
    System.out.print(i + " ,");
}
```

So, basically it will print like this for example 0,1,2,3,.But as you can see there is
an extra comma after the number. Is there a way to code this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Naive solution: only print it if `i != something.length - 1`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For example

```
for(int i=0; i < something.length; i++){
    System.out.print(i + i==something.length-1 ? "":" ,");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Just made some small adjustments System.out.print(i==something.length-1 ? "":" , ");